# Can a variable be changed within a block?

Tags: ruby

Let's go to the code directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
 require 'tk'


class Epg

def initialize
    @var = "bad"    
    @cvs = nil  
    @items_demo = TkRoot.new() {title "EPG"}
    TkFrame.new(@items_demo) {|cf|
          @var = "good" 
          @cvs = TkCanvas.new(cf) {|c|}
        puts  "@cvs 1  is #{@cvs}"
        puts  "@var 1 is #{@var}"
    }.pack('side'=>'top', 'fill'=>'both', 'expand'=>'yes')

    puts  "@cvs 2 is #{@cvs}"
    puts  "@var 2 is #{@var}"

end #initialize

def test
    @var = "bad"
    puts " @var 3 :#{@var}"
    (1..3).each {|x| @var="good"}
    puts " @var 4 :#{@var}"
end
 end

 e= Epg.new 
 e.test
```

Here is the output:

```
@cvs 1  is #<Tk::Canvas:0xb7cecb08>
@var 1 is good
@cvs 2 is 
@var 2 is bad           #@var has NOT been changed by the code in the block
@var 3 :bad
@var 4 :good            #@var has been changed by the code in the block
```

Why we see different behavior here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of blocks as closing over both the set of local variables and the current `self`.

In Ruby, you will **always** have access to local variables, no matter what. The `self` encapsulates instance methods on the current object as well as instance variables.

Consider the following code:

```
class Table
  def initialize(legs)
    @legs = legs
  end

  def with_legs
    yield @legs
  end
end
```

And then:

```
def some_calling_method
  name = "Yehuda"
  Table.new(4) {|legs| puts "#{name} gnaws off one of the #{legs} legs" }
end
```

By Ruby's block semantics, you can be assured that `name` will be available inside the block, even without looking at the method you're calling.

However, consider the following:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def gnaw
    Table.new(4).with_legs do |legs| 
      puts "#{@name} gnaws off one of the #{legs} legs"
    end
  end
end

Person.new("Yehuda").gnaw
```

In this case, we are accessing the `@name` instance variable from inside the block. It works great in this case, but is not guaranteed. What if we implemented table a bit differently:

```
class Table
  def initialize(legs)
    @legs = legs
  end

  def with_legs(&block)
    self.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

Effectively, what we're saying is "evaluate the block in the context of a **different** self." In this case, we are evaluating the block in the context of the table. Why would you do that?

```
class Leg
  attr_accessor :number
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end
end

class Table
  def initialize(legs)
    @legs = legs
  end

  def with_leg(&block)
    Leg.new(rand(@legs).instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

Now, you could do:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def gnaw
    Table.new(4).with_leg do
      puts "I'm gnawing off one of leg #{number}"
    end
  end
end
```

If you wanted access to the person object inside of the block, you'd have to do:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def gnaw
    my_name = name
    Table.new(4).with_leg do
      puts "#{my_name} is gnawing off one of leg #{number}"
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the use of instance_eval can make it simpler and less bulky to access methods of a far-off object inside a block, but comes at the cost of making the `self` unaccessible. The technique is usually used in DSLs, where a number of methods are injected into the block, but the self doesn't matter that much.

This is what's happening with Tk; they're using instance_eval to inject their own `self` into the block, which is wiping your `self` clean.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is that TkFrame.new uses instance_eval and thus the assignment @var = "good" changes the instance variable of TkFrame.  Try this out:

```
class A
  def initialize(&b)
    instance_eval(&b)
  end
end

class B
  def initialize
    @x = 10
    @a = A.new do
      @x = 20
    end
  end
end

p B.new
```

This is what you'll see:

```
#<B:0x10141314 @x=10, @a=#<A:0x10141300 @x=20>>
```

Comment: Did you have a typo? Does it should be "the assignment @var = "good" _did not_ changes the instance variable of TkFrame". As @x is still 10 but not 20 in your example.

Comment: YSE.the assignment @var = "good" changes the instance variable of TkFrame but can not change the intance variable of Epg.

Comment: I am not sure how to read your comment.  This is exactly what I said, didn't I?  So do you agree that there is no typo?