# Ruby + Tk command binding - scope issue?

Tags: ruby, scope, tk-toolkit

So I have this app

```
require 'tk'
class Foo
  def my_fancy_function
    puts "hello, world!"
  end

  def initialize
    @root = TkRoot.new{title "Hello, world!"}
    frame = TkFrame.new
    my_fancy_button = TkButton.new(frame) do
      text "Press meee"
      command {my_fancy_function}
      pack
    end
    frame.pack
    Tk.mainloop
  end
end

bar = Foo.new
```

But if I press the button, I get "NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_fancy_function' for #<TkButton:..."

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something trivial related to scope... how do I bind that command to the button correctly?

Edit: Okay, if I change my `my_fancy_button` block to parameters, i.e.

```
my_fancy_button = TkButton.new(frame, :text => "Press meee", :command => proc{my_fancy_function}).pack
```

Then it works. But why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put a

```
p self
```

into the `do ... end` block of your code, then you'll probably find out that the current scope is different than your `Foo` object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, passing blocks to `Tk` constructors is unnecessary. The resulting scope is confusing, so I think it should be discouraged.

Examples of same which contain only literal values are inflexible, and teach a bad habit.

Here, a minimal change to your program makes it work, while maintaining readability:

```rb
require 'tk'
class Foo
  def my_fancy_function
    puts "hello, world!"
  end

  def initialize
    @root = TkRoot.new{title "Hello, world!"}
    frame = TkFrame.new
    my_fancy_button = begin
      b = TkButton.new frame
      b.text "Press meee"
      b.command {my_fancy_function}
      b.pack
    end
    frame.pack
    Tk.mainloop
  end
end

bar = Foo.new
```

It works for me using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7.

Comment: See also this extremely valuable [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1072504/1136063) which explains block scope.