# Ruby / TK button event handler code not firing as expected

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

The following code creates 3 buttons and adds a handler to each one. The Quit button works, the Give Up button produces an error NameError unknown option settings_change and suggests that an object has been deleted. Same with the Next button.  The code works ok when I put the event handlers outside the class.

It turns out that if a callback is created by first doing something like next_note_proc = proc {next_note}, then in the button creation do command next_note_proc.  Why does this work??

Why do the callbacks work differently when inside or outside the class?

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

class App

  def next_note
    puts "Got next note"
  end

  def settings_change
    puts "Got settings change"
  end

  def quit
    puts "Got exit"
    exit(1)
  end

  def initialize
    $number_correct = TkVariable.new;
    $mode = TkVariable.new

    @root = TkRoot.new {title "Music Training"}
    @content = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(@root) {padding "0 0 0 0"}.grid( :sticky => 'nsew')

    @a = Tk::Tile::Button.new(@content) {text 'Next'; command {next_note}}.grid( :column => 1, :row => 1, :sticky => 'w')
    @b = Tk::Tile::Button.new(@content) {text 'Give up'; command {settings_change}}.grid( :column => 2, :row => 1, :sticky => 'w')
    @c = Tk::Tile::Button.new(@content) {text 'Quit'; command {quit}}.grid( :column => 2, :row => 2, :sticky => 'w')
    TkWinfo.children(@content).each {|w| TkGrid.configure w, :padx => 0, :pady => 0}

    @c.bind("1") {quit}
    @a.bind("1") {next_note}
    @b.bind("1") {settings_change}

    puts "Starting up"
  end

   def run
     Tk.mainloop
   end  

end

the_app = App.new
the_app.run
```

Comment: Upon reflection this is the same as question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723101/ruby-tk-command-binding-scope-issue

Comment: Just don't understand what is going on as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands executed from buttons run in the global context, but `settings_change`, `quit` and `next_note` are in the context of the class. When you use the `proc` command it creates a new `Proc` object which calls the method, and which can be called from other contexts.

The reason the `quit` command *seems* to work is probably because there is another `quit` command at the global scope that is getting called -- it is almost certainly not calling the `quit` method of the `App` object. You can verify that by adding a print statement in the `quit` method.