# Referring to self in Ruby/Tk

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I think I'm having trouble with the syntax for how an object refers to itself, specifically when used in Tk callbacks. 
Sample code:

```
class MyDialog
   def initialize
      @self = self
   end

   def makeButton          
      TkButton.new(myFrame) do
         text "Do Cool Stuf"
         command @self.buttonCallback
         pack('side'=>'top')
      end
   end

   def buttonCallback
       // stuff
   end
end
```

This seems just fine, but when I click on the button, I get an error saying

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `buttonCallback' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I make the button press call into the instance of MyDialog that created it?

Comment: do you need to use @self here?  I'm not familiar with Tk but `command buttonCallback` seems like it would be valid.

Comment: I have tried that, but it does not work either. I get an error which says that `buttonCallback` is an unknown method in `TkButton`.

Comment: If I move the definition of `butonCallback` outside the definition of `class MyDialog` then it works. But then `buttonCallback` is not a method on the class, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was similar to [Ruby + Tk command binding - scope issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1723101/4168080) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2113103/4168080) gave me the clue I needed to make it work.

```
def makeButton          
  myself = @self
  TkButton.new(myFrame) do
     text "Do Cool Stuf"
     print "DEBUG: self=#{self} @self=#{@self} myself=#{myself}\n"
     command(proc{myself.buttonCallback})
     pack('side'=>'top')
  end
end
```

For reference, here is what the debug printed:

```
DEBUG: self=#<Tk::Button:0x3db6468> @self= myself=#<ManualEntry:0x2274690>
```